# How local variable can change the value of global variable in cpp

Tags: c++, scope, global-variables, local-variables

Here, how can the operation n / 10 which is inside the inner loop, while(n>0), can change the value of n which is inside the same while loop. How the operation of local variable which is inside the inner while loop can change the value of upper level scope variable which is outside the while loop.

[image: code I've written]

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: The expression `n/10`  (where `n` is an `int`) does not change the value of `n`.   However, it gives a result that is not equal to `n` (unless `n` is zero), and the assignment `n = n/10` changes the value of `n` to that result.       A variable in an outer scope is accessible within an inner scope (but not the reverse) which is why your loop can change the value of `n` which is outside the loop.   If such a thing wasn't allowed it would be impossible to achieve many of the things that are possible with loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can the operation n / 10 which is inside the inner loop, while(n>0), can change the value of n which is inside the same while loop.

For the same reason that `digit_sum = digit_sum + last_digit;` can change the value of `digit_sum`, even though it is declared outside of the loop, same as `n`.

> How the operation of local variable which is inside the inner while loop can change the value of upper level scope variable which is outside the while loop.

Why shouldn't it be able to? `n` (and `digit_sum`) is [in scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope) inside the loop.  A variable's lifetime is the duration of the scope that it is declared in, but inner scopes also have access to it.

Comment: Okay, got it. Thanks. I didn't knew about this that inner scoped variables can also modify their values on global levels.